# How can I group OS X toggle buttons in Interface Builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

On iTunes, the view buttons are grouped together as such:

[image]

I would like to achieve this effect in my OS X app. I can't find instructions or a tutorial for this. I suspect my problem is that I don't know what terminology to use in my search.

I have an NSToolBar. I can add a single button, but I don't know how to group multiple buttons and made them dependent on each other's toggle state.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a Segmented Control. (NSSegmentedControl)

Just drag it from the object library into the toolbar, and then you can configure every cell individually.